# How to add an array to a cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I am trying to store array to cookie. I am storing my array products item in cookie array, but it throws error.

```
    $products = array();
    $item = array($id => $name);
    print_r($item);
    $products[] = $item;
    setcookie('products',json_encode($products),strtotime( '+1 day' ));
    var_dump($_COOKIE['products']);
```

The above code prints

> Array (
>       [4] => Rug Rat ) 
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: products in
>   **D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\includes\classes\products.php**
>   on line **43**
>  NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are set when the response is sent to the client. This means that you won't be able to access them from PHP code until the next request. See the documentation for `setcookie()` function, section Common Pitfalls:

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

So, unless you `echo` anything, or do anything else that causes the response headers to be sent, you should see `var_dump`ed cookie content after you refresh the page. In your code, there's `print_r($item);` before `setcookie()` is called, so you're probably getting a `headers already sent` warning, and the cookie is never set.

One way or another, it's rarely safe to assume that an array index is set, especially in a superglobal, like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, etc. You should always check with `isset()` or `array_key_exists` if the index is really set.

Comment: I am using ajax to update the cookie.. .It throws the same error for each request. not just first request. I tried reloading the page after first request but it throws the same error for the ajax request

Comment: You're calling `print_r` before `setcookie()`. Remove `print_r()` and cookie should work now.